# How to delete item from an array in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I've seen this answered here numerous times but it's not working for me.  I need to remove an item from an array but the index continues returning -1.

```js
  deleteItinerary(id: string) {
    this.dataSvc.removeItinerary(id);
    console.log('id', id);
    const index = this.itineraries.indexOf(id);
    console.log('array', this.itineraries);
    console.log('index', index);
  }
```

I've seen this answered here that we should use array.indexOf().  I'm doing a console log to verify the id is correct and that it exists within the array but the index keeps giving me -1.

Thanks for your help

Comment: How exactly are you removing your element from the array? Can we see the code for tha?

Comment: I was going to use this example:

    if (index !== -1) {
        this.data.splice(index, 1);
    }

Comment: mongo ObjectID !== string, and indexOf will not work, use `.findIndex(mongoId => mongoId.equals(id))`

Comment: I'm not using Mongo, this is using a firebase backend.

Comment: @QuanHodges Thanks. Just to clarify, is each element in the array an `object`? Or `string`? or `number`?

Comment: It's an object.  I'm deleted these objects from the array and I want the ion-list to reflect that immediately upon deleting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since each element in the array is an `object`, which contains the property of `id` which is of type `string`, you can simply use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get rid of that element.

```js
const data = [{id:'2'}, {id:'5'}, {id:'9'}];

const removeItinerary = (removeId) => {
  const res = data.filter(obj => obj.id !== removeId);
  return res;
}

console.log(removeItinerary('5'));
```

[Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will not work in your instance, unless you provide the index of the object you want to remove.

If you insist on using `Array.splice()`, first, you will need to find the index of the object in that array that matches the specific id.

```
const index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.id === removeId)
```

Next, you use Array.splice to remove the object from the array.

```
if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

```js
const data = [{id:'2'}, {id:'5'}, {id:'9'}];

const removeItinerary = (removeId) => {
  const index = data.findIndex(el => el.id === '5')
  if (index > -1) {
    data.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return data;
}

console.log(removeItinerary('5'));
```